# What's the most performant all JavaScript charting option for real-time data via websockets?

Tags: javascript, charts

The ones I've seen so far look nice but make my dual core MBP look like its playing a flash video. Anyone seeing good performance?

Comment: After some more experience with JS charting. I have to say so far D3 has proven most performant.

Answer (score 1):

I know this is old but for the benefit of anyone still looking, [Smoothie Charts](http://smoothiecharts.org/) is pretty cool.